# VS2017 Community "Windows application packaging project" does not show

Tags: visual-studio

In my VS2017 community installation there is no option to create "Windows Application Packaging Project" as shown in Microsoft introduction. I'm not quite sure why it is like that? Because I installed .Net Framework 4.6.1 (see fig). Is that the Community version does not support packaging for Windows app?

[image]

Comment: What version of visual studio 2017 do you have?  In the help about menu option you will see it.  I am looking for a number like 15.5 not community.  Do you have the latest windows 10 installed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root As the article indicates, you need to have "Desktop Bridge" installed. You vanilla Visual Studio installation is not enough.

Comment: it's version 15.2 (26430.16) release. My windows is 1709 (build 16299.192)

Answer (score 3):

Im creating a new answer instead of commenting because i dont have the required reputation.

I had visual studio 2017 version 15.9.15 installed but i still couldnt find the Windows Application Packaging Project, so i clicked modify on my version from the Visual Studio Installer and it turned out that i hadnt installed UWP development in the first place.

[image]